# BlocksKit and Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just updated to Xcode 4.5 an am getting this error

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:

I've tried compiling BlocksKit but get this error /Users/toddbates/Desktop/ios demos/BlocksKit/A2DynamicDelegate/libffi/ios/src/x86/darwin.S:34:10: 'fficonfig.h' file not found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the linker error, remove `armv7s` from your `valid architectures` entry within your build-settings.

Comment: To expand on that, the library wasn't built with armv7s, so asking xcode to build with armv7s code means the library can't be linked. Removing armv7s isn't a big deal; it only adds some iPhone 5 optimizations. Ideally the library should be built with armv7s someday.

Answer (score 0):

I added BlocksKit using Cocoapods and everything works. Theres a small learning curve to use it, but I can see its advantages after that. Seems that the precompiled framework at https://github.com/rakumx/BlocksKitFramework.framework may be stale. Still not sure why the BlocksKit project itself doesn't compile.